# Call a variable from another Class in python

Tags: python, qt, class, pyqt, class-variables

I am trying to call a variable from a Class of MainWindow to another class of a Dialog, I know that this question was asked before but I tried all the given answers and I couldn't make it work as I am still beginner with python.

My code is as below, (the variable that I want to call is `self.Value`, considering that I need it to be in the same While loop):

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import time
from threading import Event, Thread

from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from savedialog import Ui_saveDialog
from plot import Plot

from PyQt4.Qt import QString, QFileDialog


from pylab import *

import threading

#DH11 tempSensor Library
import Adafruit_DHT

#Library to find FFT and FFTshift 
from scipy.fftpack import fft, fftshift

from numpy import linspace

#Library to find Max and Min 
from operator import itemgetter

class dataAcquisition(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(dataAcquisition, self).__init__(parent)
        #threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.startButton_clicked)
        self.th = Thread(target = self.runValue)
        self.popSave = saveDialog()

        self.status = False
    def runValue(self):
        Fs = 8000
        N = 256
        f = linspace(-Fs/2, Fs/2, N)

        X = []
        Y = []
        MaxMin = []
        self.i = 0.0

        ax1 = subplot(2, 1, 1)
        Line1 = plot(0,0,'r-')[0]

        ax2 = subplot(2, 1, 2)
        Line2 = plot(f,0*f,'r-')[0]

        self.status = True
        while (self.status):

            self.Value = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 4)[1]        

            X.append(self.i)
            Y.append(self.Value)

            FFT = log10(abs(fft(Y, N)))
            FFT = fftshift(FFT)

            Line1.set_xdata(X)
            Line1.set_ydata(Y)

            ax1.relim()
            ax1.autoscale_view()

            Line2.set_ydata(FFT)
            ax2.relim()
            ax2.autoscale_view()

            for k in Y:
                for MM in range(int(k)):
                    MaxMin.append(MM)

            self.MaxValue = max(MaxMin)
            self.MinValue = min(MaxMin)

            self.i += 0.10
            pause(0.01)

            self.lcdNumber_value.display(self.Value)
            self.lcdNumber_MaxValue.display(self.MaxValue)
            self.lcdNumber_MinValue.display(self.MinValue)

    def startButton_clicked(self):
        self.th.start()      
        self.popSave.show()

class saveDialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_saveDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(saveDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        flags = QtCore.Qt.Drawer | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
        self.setWindowFlags(flags)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.Unlimited_NOVs)

        self.saveOkButton.clicked.connect(self.acceptOKButtonClicked)

        self.NOVs = 0.0

        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.spinBox_value_changed)

    def Unlimited_NOVs (self, state):
        if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.NOVs = 5

    def spinBox_value_changed (self):
        self.NOVs = self.spinBox.value()

    def acceptOKButtonClicked(self):

        #Here I want to call self.Value

        i = 1
        while True:
            Name = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', 'sessionData.txt')
            self.fName = open(Name %i ,"w")

            i += 1
            c = 1
            while c <= self.NOVs:
                c += 1

                self.fName.write(str(self.Value))
                self.fName.write("\n")

            else:
                self.fName.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = dataAcquisition()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `while True` will freeze your program.

Comment: send this value directly as parameter in `def __init__(self, parent=None, value):` or try `parent.Value` but you had to send parent to Dialog `self.popSave = saveDialog(self)`

Comment: You could explain what you want to do since you do not understand your logic

Comment: BTW: if you run `thread` then it could be safe to use `queue` to send data from `thread` to main thread.

Comment: What do you want to do with self.Value?

Comment: `saveDialog` can starts before thread creates `self.Value`. Better create `self.Value` in `__init__` with some default value.

Comment: Consider your dataAcquisition and some other object that exists within a while loop wants to share the same reference (variable) to some object in memory.  Who is creating this shared object? Is this object being shared across threads? Without knowing full context - our answers could be a bigger headache for you.

Comment: BTW: better create minimal, working code with your problem - so everyone could run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send `parent` to dialog and then you have access to main window - `self.parent.Value`

But you should create variable with some default value in `__init__` if you want to use it in dialog `__init__`

BTW: we use `CamelCase` names for classes - ie. `QPushButton` and `DataAcquisition`, `SaveDialog`

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.Qt import QString, QFileDialog
from threading import Event, Thread
import sys
import time

class DataAcquisition(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DataAcquisition, self).__init__(parent)

        self.startButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self, text="Show Dialog")
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.startButton_clicked)

        self.th = Thread(target = self.runValue)

        # create variable with default value
        self.Value = "Hello World!"

        # send parent (self) to Dialog
        self.popSave = SaveDialog(self)

    def runValue(self):
        self.Value = 0
        while True:
            self.Value += 1
            time.sleep(1)

    def startButton_clicked(self):
        self.th.start()      
        self.popSave.show()

class SaveDialog(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SaveDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        # this value is get when Dialog is create, not when is executed `show()`
        # so it gets default value "Hello World!"
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self, text=self.parent().Value)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton(self, text="Update label")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def button_clicked(self):
        # get current value from parent
        self.label.setText(str(self.parent().Value))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = DataAcquisition()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @furas, but could you please make the same thing with on my original code? As I already have formed my widgets and buttons.

Comment: @M.Lagha you can do it yourself - you need `SaveDialog(self)`, `self.parent = parent` and `self.parent.Value` - that's all.

Comment: @M.Lagha - I checked, you can need even less because it has method `self.parent()` - so you have to send parent (`self`) to dialog `self.popSave = saveDialog(self)` and later you can use `self.parent().Value`